# axios post dosent send any data to django

Tags: django, react-native, axios, fetch

i use react-native for my front-end and django for my backend on pythonanywhere .
my front end codes :

```
  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mohammadss.pythonanywhere.com/login',
    // url: '127.0.0.1:8000/login',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
    },
    data: qs.stringify({
      Hello: 'Hello?',
    }),
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

and my backend code :

```
def Login(request):
res = request.POST ;
return JsonResponse(res , JSONEncoder)
```

but it dosent return anything . with Postman everything is good . and with fetch() function i can see result :

```
fetch('http://mohammadss.pythonanywhere.com/login/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  body: qs.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
}).then(reponse => {
  reponse.json().then(RES => {
    console.log(RES);
  });
});
```

but axios dosent work .

Comment: what error do you get in console.log?

Comment: You are probably facing `CORS` errors. Is your `CORS` configured correctly in your django's settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my way . things i did :
1- installed [[[django-cors-headers 3.2.1][1](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)][1](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) on my Pythonanywhere host . thanks to nima . ( and of course i dont know if this was necessary or not ! ) .

2- i changed my codes to :

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('username', 'myname');
data.append('password', 'blablabla');

axios
  .post('http://mohammadss.pythonanywhere.com/login/', data, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(typeof response.data.Code);
    if (response.data.Code == '1') {
      alert('Loged IN');
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

i dont know how much my codes are clean , but worked for me !